# Jquery selected option text contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make if condition of selected option of another select not the current which contains certain text string as a text and not the value.

Example:

```
<select class="Selected">
<option>Hello</option>
<option>Bye</option>
</select>
```

In the following case what I have is the fowling. a trigger of another select:

```
$(".Selected_Two").change(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.div-block').find('.Selected:contains("Bye")')) {              
    alert('Bye');
    }
});
```

So basically if the select option is selected in the select when triggering the other select will have to see alert "Bye"
But it is not working at this state. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Good idea, but what have you tried?

Comment: "f the select option is selected in the select when triggering the other select " brain exploded. Good luck mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do that `indexOf()` for **value** or `:contains` for **option text**

`indexOf()`

```
$(".Selected_Two").change(function () {
    var SelectTwoValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).closest('.div-block').find('.Selected)').val().indexOf(SelectTwoValue ) > -1) {              
        alert('Bye');
    }
});
```

`:contains` and `length`

```
$(".Selected_Two").change(function () {
    var SelectTwoValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).closest('.div-block').find('.Selected option:selected:contains("'+SelectTwoValue+'")').length > 0) {              
       alert('Bye');
    }
});
```

*Maybe you'll need to work around `.val().indexOf()` and `:contains("'+SelectTwoValue+'")').length` .. but I think you got the point*

Comment: Have a great day @JohnSiniger :-)